# How to serve a static hello world type HTML document with BaseX?

Tags: html, docker, webserver, jetty, basex

In this Docker [container](https://hub.docker.com/r/basex/basexhttp/) for BaseX, where can I put `foo.html` so that Jetty will [serve](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63750362/4531180) the page?

```
bash-4.4# 
bash-4.4# whoami
root
bash-4.4# 
bash-4.4# pwd
/srv/basex/webapp/WEB-INF
bash-4.4# 
bash-4.4# ls
data       foo.html   jetty.xml  repo       web.xml
bash-4.4# 
bash-4.4# cat foo.html 
<html>
<header><title>This is title</title></header>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>


bash-4.4# 
bash-4.4# head web.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
  xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" 
  version="4.0">
    
  <display-name>BaseX: The XML Database and XQuery Processor</display-name>
  <description>HTTP Services</description>
    
bash-4.4#
```

And, what would be the expected URL to find `foo.html` at?

Do I need to grant permissions first?

Comment: Can you provide your image's Dockerfile, or otherwise describe what image you're working from?  How are you launching the container?  What have you already tried?

Comment: I added a link @DavidMaze to docker hub

Comment: basex 9.4.x seems to be based on jetty 9.4.x, which is Servlet 3.1 (you'll need to downgrade your servlet declared version in your WEB-INF/web.xml from 4.0 to 3.1 at least)