# how to publish an XML result from basexserver?

Tags: xml, webserver, jetty, xquery, basex

I was [mucking](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63750956/4531180) around with `basexserver` as [installed](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man1/basexserver.1.html) on `Ubuntu` and came across a `-c` flag but am not getting results:

```
nicholas $ 
nicholas $ lynx http://localhost:1984/ --dump
```

which just hangs, as does a standard web browser.  How do I publish the below `xml` result?

```
nicholas $ 
nicholas $ cat query.xq 
xquery version "3.0";

for $bar in db:open("foo")
let $baz := $bar
return <query_results>{$baz}</query_results>


    nicholas $ 
    nicholas $ cat helloworld 
    SHOW USERS
    LIST
    #GRANT all on foo to admin
    RUN query.xq
    nicholas $ 
    nicholas $ basex query.xq 
    <query_results>
      <foo>bar</foo>
    </query_results>nicholas $ 
    nicholas $ 
    nicholas $ basexserver -c helloworld
    Username  Permission  
    --------------------
    admin     admin       
    
    1 user(s).
    Name  Resources  Size  Input Path  
    ---------------------------------
    foo   1          4599              
    
    1 database(s).
    <query_results>
      <foo>bar</foo>
    </query_results>BaseX 9.0.1 [Server]
    Server was started (port: 1984).
    ^CServer was stopped (port: 1984).
    nicholas $
```

The above `query_results` aren't available on localhost.  How do I make them available?

Comment: I think you can connect to that BaseX server with a BaseX client i.e. either using the command line client BaseX comes with or using a client program based on the client examples. The communication is over TCP/IP, I don't think a web browser will make the right request using HTTP. As for the XML, do you want to have that stored in a database and then subsequently retrieved by a client from the database?

Comment: yes, I can use the BaseX console.  Instead, how do I view query results from `basexserver` with a web browser?  Put differently, how does a web browser "query" the `basexserver`?

Comment: For that you integrate the BaseX server into an Java EE webapp https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Web_Application that listens on port 8984 by default and by default provides services using RESTXQ, REST, WebSockets or for static pages. For simply accessing resources in a db using REST you can load e.g. `http://localhost:8984/rest/db-name/resource-name`, see https://docs.basex.org/wiki/REST.

Comment: To append on what @MartinHonnen is saying the simplest way is to use RestXQ, this way you don't have to bringt your own Java EE server and stuff. You simply start the webserver using `basexhttp` (see https://docs.basex.org/wiki/Web_Application for details) and use RESTXQ (see https://docs.basex.org/wiki/RESTXQ)